# Error with redirect URI when trying to authenticate user (Spotipy library)

Tags: spotify, spotipy

I am trying to use the Spotify API through the python wrapper library Spotipy. I have set up environment variables (specifically the client id and client secret as well as redirect URI) to authenticate. However, whenever I try to access something that needs this authorization (i.e. accessing a user's playlist) I get the following error: tcgetpgrp  failed: Not a tty. It seems to happen whenever I access the redirect URI for authorization. I have tried a few URI's, like example.com/callback and localhost:8080 but none of these seem to work. Here is the code I have so far:

```
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth

scope = "user-library-read"

sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(scope=scope))

def edit_playlist(name):
    # Find playlist for user under the name provided
    print(sp.current_user_playlists())

# Return some generic done message
print("Edited!")
```

I can't seem to find out what the error message means, so an explanation of that would be helpful. Similarly, what should I make my redirect URI? (Not a specific URL, but ideas of what a proper redirect URI should be). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I had at some point accidentally removed the redirect URI in my dashboard. Also, it helped to use localhost:8888/callback instead of other URL's.